# TeamCity 9.1.5: Build configuration's schedule trigger is flaky (works sometimes)

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.1

I have some tests configured to run every morning at 05:00 UTC-4.

The triggers seems to be spotty however. It has ran a number of times, including on May 4th and May 5th, but it has failed to run this morning as well as on a few other days since I've configured the trigger.

[image: As you can see, May 4th and 5th triggers worked. Nothing at 05:00 for May 6th however.]
[image: The schedule trigger]

**Anyone know what might be causing this? Is there any way to retrace why the triggers failed to run?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue.

In the trigger properties, there is a checkbox that is **check marked by default** when the trigger is created:

> Trigger only if there are pending changes

[image: trigger properties]

I unchecked it, and I expect it will work as expected from here on. I want my tests to run daily, regardless of whether there was changes to the testcases or not.